# How to load multiple xibs in a single xib?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, nsarray, xib

I've created 4 xibs of width 200,height 200 for a purpose...but if i want to load all xib in a single xib i dont know to achieve that..I got a couple of ideas

1.Can we make all the xib to load by group of arrays?

2.Can we declare NSBUNDLE code at appdelegate.m file?..

Comment: Have you explored storyboards? They are essentially collections of xibs, with some fancy new features like no-code-needed navigation between them, etc. Is there a reason storyboards would not be an option?

Comment: @ctrahey:yes...I have deploy on ios4.3 simulator..I know that it wont support storyboard concepts...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

each xib must have a class for control it. So you now must have 4 xib , 4 .h and 4 .m files. Now create another view controller with xib, .m and .h (MainViewController).
Now import all the class.
in MainController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Xib1Class.h"
#import "Xib2Class.h"
#import "Xib3Class.h"
#import "Xib4Class.h"

@interface MainViewController : UIViewController {

    Xib1Class *xib1Class;
    Xib2Class *xib2Class;
    Xib3Class *xib3Class;
    Xib4Class *xib4Class;

}

@end
```

in viewDidLoad of MainViewController.m

```
xib1Class = [[Xib1Class alloc] initWithNibName:@"Xib1Class" bundle:nil];
xib2Class = [[Xib2Class alloc] initWithNibName:@"Xib2Class" bundle:nil];
xib3Class = [[Xib3Class alloc] initWithNibName:@"Xib3Class" bundle:nil];
xib4Class = [[Xib4Class alloc] initWithNibName:@"Xib4Class" bundle:nil];

//set the frame
xib1Class.view.frame = CGRectMake(x,y,w,h);
..........
//put in main view
[self.view addSubView:xib1class.view];
//the same for 2-3-4
```

remember to manage memory.
Hope this help u.